# Finding isotopes of find corresponding string with two differences exactly predifined

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of names (sum formulas) e.g.

```
"C 4 H 15 O 7"
"C 13 H 17 O 7"
"C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7"
"C 12 Cxiv 1 H 17 O 7"
"C 24 H 15 O 4"
"C 32 H 13 O 10"
"C 12 Cxiv 1 H 24 N 1"
```

In my data the vector is much longer. So how can I find a universal solution to find matches that differ in the following: Instead of one C there is one Cxiv in the string. All other compounds (H x,O x,N x...) should be the same. In other words I want to find the same sum formulas where one C is substituted by a C14 isotope. As result I want to create a vector that becomes one at the place of a string containing Cxiv if there is a match found and in all other cases becomes 0.
so for the example above the vector would look like this:

```
vec
0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
Many thanks!

Comment: shouldnt the last one be 1?

Comment: `as.integer(grepl('Cxiv', x))`?

Comment: no because it has no match or in other words no corresponding sum formula without Cxiv and instead one more C. So the last one has to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
# split each string by space into separate elements in a list
l <- strsplit(x, ' ')

# check which list parts contain 'Cxiv'
i <- sapply(l, function(v) any(v == 'Cxiv'))

# for those that contain 'Cxiv' increase the second number with 1
# and remove the 'Cxiv 1' part
l[i] <- lapply(l[i], function(v) {
  v[2] <- as.character(as.numeric(v[2]) + 1);
  v[-c(which(v == 'Cxiv') + 0:1)]
})    

# check which are duplicates
as.integer(duplicated(l))
```

gives:

> ```
> [1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
> ```

If you want to meet the requirement as stated in the comment (when the chemical formula with `Cxiv` comes first), you need to change the last step to:

```
as.integer((duplicated(l) | duplicated(l, fromLast = TRUE)) & grepl('Cxiv',x))
```

Tested on new example data (`x2`) you will get:

> ```
> [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
> ```

---

Used data:

```
x <- c("C 4 H 15 O 7","C 13 H 17 O 7","C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7","C 12 Cxiv 1 H 17 O 7",
       "C 24 H 15 O 4","C 32 H 13 O 10","C 12 Cxiv 1 H 24 N 1")
```

New data:

```
x2 <- c("C 4 H 15 O 7","C 13 H 17 O 7","C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7","C 12 Cxiv 1 H 17 O 7",
        "C 24 H 15 O 4","C 12 Cxiv 1 H 24 N 1","C 32 H 13 O 10","C 13 H 24 N 1")
```

Comment: First of all! Many thanks.  I think this fits this example but might not be what I meant by checking for isotopes. Does this solutions takes care of equal numbers when checking? e.g. adding a "C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 6" in the above example the result should not become 1 as there is one O missing.

Comment: @JmO This doesn't look at the numbers. Could you explain better what you are considering equal? In the example data the 3rd & 4th element aren't exactly the same either.

Comment: I have a chemical sum formula e.g. "C 4 H 15 O 7" in the above example. Now I want to find the Cxiv isotope which means it has the same amount of H so 15, the same amount of O so 7 and one less C so C 3. Instead of one less C there is one additional Cxiv 1 which leads to the sum formula: "C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7". So "C 4 H 15 O 7" is a positive match. At the rowindex of "C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7" the result vector should become 1. Does this help? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks a lot! just one add. does this hold if the Cxiv is above its match in order e.g. when in the example above "C 3 Cxiv 1 H 15 O 7" has the rowindex 1 and not 3 and its match "C 4 H 15 O 7" rowindex 3 and not 1. as this would give 0011000 as well but the 1 is now at "C 4 H 15 O 7" because its the duplicate now but 1´s should only be at the match containing Cxiv. Thanks a lot!