# Find "pairwise" indices for every duplicate in list of strings

Tags: r, string, indexing, string-matching

After changing a string part element Ax, I want to find the respective index of duplicates of this string as explained below in a very long vector of strings. Consider:

```
D <- data.frame(string=c("A 4 B 15 C 7","A 13 B 17 C 7","A 3 Ax 1 B 15 C 7","A 12 Ax 1 B 17 C 7","A 24 B 15 C 4","A 32 B 13 C 10","A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1","A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1","A 13 B 24 D 1"))

# string
"A 4 B 15 C 7"
"A 13 B 17 C 7"
"A 3 Ax 1 B 15 C 7"
"A 12 Ax 1 B 17 C 7"
"A 24 B 15 C 4"
"A 32 B 13 C 10"
"A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1"
"A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1"
"A 13 B 24 D 1"
```

I now increase every A by its Ax and delete Ax, so I will have duplicates:

```
l <- strsplit(as.character(D$string), ' ')

# check which list parts contain 'Ax'
i <- sapply(l, function(v) any(v == 'Ax'))

# for those that contain 'Ax' increase the second number with 1
# and remove the 'Ax 1' part
l[i] <- lapply(l[i], function(v) {
  v[2] <- as.character(as.numeric(v[2]) + 1);
  v[-c(which(v == 'Ax') + 0:1)]
})    

# check which are duplicates
 k<-data.frame(k=as.integer(duplicated(l)))
 k1<-data.frame(k=as.integer(duplicated(l,fromLast = TRUE)))
```

which is solved here: [Finding isotopes of find corresponding string with two differences exactly predifined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438924/finding-isotopes-of-find-corresponding-string-with-two-differences-exactly-predi/44439299?noredirect=1#comment75884943_44439299)

**But** how can I check now at which position in the original data frame `D` I have the duplicate match between the Ax value and its A counterpart? my idea is as follows: where `h` indicates whether there is a Ax(1) or not (0) in the row of `D`

```
h<-c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)


inds <- lapply(1:length(h[h==1 & (k==1 | k1==1)]), function(x) which(paste0(l[h==1 & (k==1 | k1==1)], collapse = NULL) %in% as.vector(l[h==1 & (k==1 | k1==1)][x])))

inds<-unlist(inds)

inds:
1
2
3
3
```

I could check if `inds` is correct by inserting inds in the original data.frame:

```
X<-data.frame(A=A[h==0 & (k==1 | k1==1),1][inds],Ax=A[h==1 & (k==1 | k1==1),1])
```

where the first column has the A value and the second its corresponding Ax value

**but** besides this takes a lot of time it seems not to give the correct index always and what if `inds` has more than one match this does not work anymore ?

Does anybody has an idea how to improve/ make this correct and handling multiple matches? In the end I want something like the `inds` vector (or as list if there are multiple matches in a row), so that I know (if there is a duplicate) at which position my A string has its Ax counterpart in the original data.frame `D`. 
Any other method to find the respective index of an A string and its corresponding Ax string would be welcome, too.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long inefficient (can be improved easily) way of tackling your issue.

```
D%>%
mutate(string = as.character(string),spaces = str_count( . ,' ')+1)%>%
magrittr::set_colnames(c("strings", "spaces"))%>%
separate(col =  strings, into = paste("col", 1:max(.$spaces), sep = ""))%>%
mutate(col2 = as.numeric(col2),  col4 = as.numeric(col4))%>%
mutate(col2 = ifelse(col4 == 1 & col3 == "Ax", col2+col4, col2),
       col4 = ifelse(col3 == "Ax", "", col4))%>%
mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.)|. == "Ax", NA)))%>%
select(-spaces)%>%
unite(col = "D",colnames(.), sep = " ")%>%
mutate(D = gsub(" NA |NA", "", D))

               D
1   A 4 B 15 C 7
2  A 13 B 17 C 7
3   A 4 B 15 C 7
4  A 13 B 17 C 7
5  A 24 B 15 C 4
6 A 32 B 13 C 10
7  A 13 B 24 D 1
8  A 13 B 24 D 1
9  A 13 B 24 D 1
```

To get the indexes of your 'duplicate' string issue, just use `duplicate()` to return an vector of **TRUE/FALSE** values followed by `which()` to get the indexes, just use:

```
data%>%
duplicated()%>%
which()
```

Thus, your duplicated data is shown through the following:

```
D%>%
mutate(string = as.character(string),spaces = str_count( . ,' ')+1)%>%
magrittr::set_colnames(c("strings", "spaces"))%>%
separate(col =  strings, into = paste("col", 1:max(.$spaces), sep = ""))%>%
mutate(col2 = as.numeric(col2),  col4 = as.numeric(col4))%>%
mutate(col2 = ifelse(col4 == 1 & col3 == "Ax", col2+col4, col2),
       col4 = ifelse(col3 == "Ax", "", col4))%>%
mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.)|. == "Ax", NA)))%>%
select(-spaces)%>%
unite(col = "D",colnames(.), sep = " ")%>%
mutate(D = gsub(" NA |NA", "", D))%>%
duplicated()%>%
which()

[1] 3 4 8 9
```

I know the process looks rather cumbersome, so I'll see if I can condense it at a later point.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. But as I understand this correctly this in the end gives me only an index of which values are duplicated at all but not an index of the pairs of duplicates. where an A has its Ax?!

Comment: "an index of the pairs of duplicates" 

What does the result of this look like? Like this? `[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE` or `[1] 3 4 7 8`

Comment: something like: "A 3 Ax 1 B 15 C 7" 1 because "A 4 B 15 C 7"; "A 12 Ax 1 B 17 C 7" 2 because "A 13 B 17 C 7", "A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1" and  "A 12 Ax 1 B 24 D 1" 3 because "A 13 B 24 D 1" so just 1 2 3 3 like my inds vector in my question.

Comment: I'm trying to run your code above. What is `h` referencing? `inds <- lapply(1:length(h[h==1 & (k==1 | k1==1)]) ...... ` This should be the last question I ask before I solve this and edit my answer above. Thanks for your patience on this and my delayed response.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help! h is referencing the positions where there is a Ax. an h=1 indicates that the string at that positions contains an Ax, a 0 that the string has not an Ax. sry I will edit this in my question. It is equal to the i in my q but has 0 and 1 instead of True/False

Comment: So I've been thinking about this question on the side, and honestly, I don't know how my approach using the `tidyverse` would be quicker than what you'd be thinking of with `stringr` vector related operations. At the end of the day, I'd create reference columns to mark down which columns contained `Ax`, which ones contained duplicates, which ones contained... etc. It doesn't seem very efficient to answer your original question. I'll be thinking of this question on the side until I have a satisfactory answer.